# "Available width" qualifier for Android resources: Supported since which version?

Tags: android, android-resources

In the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources), in section "Available width" it reads "Added in API level 13." before mentioning some XML attributes that have been introduced as well.

But does that mean the "available width" qualifier (`wXXXdp`) is only supported in API levels 13+ or is it just those XML attributes that have become available in that SDK version?

I would like to use the "available width" in applications for API level 8+ and there is no real alternative to that qualifier, is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualifiers are ignored if the platform does not [recongize it](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2):

> Note: Some configuration qualifiers have been added since Android 1.0, so not all versions of Android support all the qualifiers. Using a new qualifier implicitly adds the platform version qualifier so that older devices are sure to ignore it.

Comment: So with old API levels, I need to use the `layout-xlarge` (etc.) qualifiers?

Comment: If you feel that you can't make it work with only 1 xml file, yes.

Comment: I don't refer to the XML tag, by the way, but to the file name qualifier (e.g. drawable-w720dp). Were these qualifiers introduced in level 13 as well or earlier?

Comment: @MarcoW. wow, even simpler answer, got my attributes and qualifiers mixed up :) Yes they're ignored.

Comment: Thank you! This proves that they are ignored, but have they really been introduced later than API level 8?

Comment: @MarcoW. the link I added where I quoted from shows a table of the valid qualifiers and API add date. Qualifiers have been around for a while eg `Screen size` (such as `xlarge`) is from API 4 and up whereas `smallestWidth`/`Available width` is 13+

Comment: Okay, found another proof here: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.2.html Thank you!